# How to stop Someone to delete the application from iPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, passwords

I am working on one application in which I need that My application not get deleted by someone. If someone wants to delete the application from iPhone, then the pop up will appear to ask the password. If the password is correct then the application gets deleted.

But I have studied that,
go to the Settings app on your device's home screen, tap "General", scroll down, tap "Restrictions", tap "Enable Restrictions", create a four digit passcode and enter it again when prompted, and then toggle "Deleting Apps" to OFF.

But this procedure will be applied for all the applications in the iPhone device. But if I want to restrict one app with password and to not be deleted by User, then what I should do for this?

Comment: Even if Apple or iOS allowed this it's wishful thinking at best that you'd be able to stop all users from deleting the app. Especially advanced users.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do this as the deletion of apps is handled by the operating system and not by individual apps.

Answer (score 0):

This type of feature can be abused, forcing iOS users to have a certain app installed. That's probably why this feature doesn't exist. And just like what Abraham mentioned, iOS handles the deletion.